# PHP Build url query from array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to build URL query from an Array that looks like that:

```
$serials = ['3804689','3801239','3555689','3804687','1404689','6804689','8844689','4104689','2704689','4604689'];
```

I would like to get query like that:

```
localhost/get?serial=3804689&serial=3801239&serial=3555689
```

(you get the idea)

I'm trying to use `http_build_query($serials, 'serial', '&amp;');` but it adds the numeric index to the prefix 'serial'.

Any idea how to remove that numeric index?

Comment: Any specific reason you'll need such an odd query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use a `foreach`:

```
$get = "localhost/get?serial=" . $serials[0];
unset( $serials[0] );
foreach( $serials AS serial ){
    $get .= "&serial=$serial;
}
```

Comment: That will get you something like `localhost/get??serial=1?serial=2?serial=3?serial=4...`.

Comment: Thanks man! I've made few adjustments but you point me to the right direction :)

Comment: Isnt that an inefficient solution. A simple implode would have worked. And moreover having same get variable isn't going to solve any purpose so it should not be encouraged

Answer (score 3):

Well you can't really have the same GET parameter in the string, After all if you try to access that variable server side, what would you use?

`$_GET['serial']` - But which serial would it get?

If you really want to get a list of serials, Simply turn the array into a string, save it as an array and there you go. for example :

`$serials = "string of serials, delimited by &"`;
    Then you can use the http build query.

Comment: Yes, But that means your node.JS API is a bit wrong, This isn't a correct way of passing arguments in as GET parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an FYI, PHP doesn't handle multiple GET variables with the same name natively.  You will have to implement something fairly custom.  If you are wanting to create a query string with multiple serial numbers, use a delimiter like `_` or `-`.

Ex: `soemthing.com/serials.php?serials=09830-20990-91234-12342`

To do something like this from an array would be simple

```
$get_uri = "?serial=" . implode("-", $serials);
```

You would be able to get the array back from a the string using an explode to

```
$serials = explode("-", $_GET['serials']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes its quite possible to have such format, you have to build it query string by indices. Like this:

No need to build the query string by hand, use `http_build_query()` in this case:

```
$serials = ['3804689','3801239','3555689','3804687','1404689','6804689','8844689','4104689','2704689','4604689'];
$temp = $serials;
unset($serials);
$serials['serial'] = $temp;
$query_string = http_build_query($serials);
echo urldecode($query_string);
// serial[0]=3804689&serial[1]=3801239&serial[2]=3555689&serial[3]=3804687&serial[4]=1404689&serial[5]=6804689&serial[6]=8844689&serial[7]=4104689&serial[8]=2704689&serial[9]=4604689
```

And then finally, if you need to process it somewhere, just access it thru `$_GET['serial'];`

```
$serials = $_GET['serial']; // this will now hold an array of serials
```

Comment: @BayssMekanique yes this is quite possible, instead of naming each individual data with other names, they could be gathered with the same name, so that when you access that query name, they will hold the list of values that you set

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
$get = "localhost/get?serial=";

$serials = ['3804689','3801239','3555689','3804687','1404689','6804689','8844689','4104689','2704689','4604689'];

$list = implode("&serial=",$serials);
echo $get.$list;
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the same GET parameter will not work this way. You will need to use an array in the get parameter:

```
localhost/get?serial[]=3804689&serial[]=3801239&serial[]=3555689
```

IF you just print $_GET through this URL, you will receive

```
Array ( [serial] => Array ( [0] => 380468 [1] => 3801239 [2]=> 3555689) )
```

Then you can do this to build your query string

```
$query_str = 'serial[]='.implode('&serials[]=',$serials);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this version.

```
$serials = ['3804689','3801239','3555689','3804687','1404689','6804689','8844689','4104689','2704689','4604689'];
$get = implode('&serials[]=',$serials);
echo '<a href="test.php?serials[]='.$get.'">test</a>';
var_dump($_GET['serials']);
```

Result

[image]